# C++, Modifying vector elements using its pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I wish to avoid switch statement by defining a pointer to a vector.
I need help to use insert and erase methods.

```
bool selectFirst = true;
std::vector<int> v1, v2;
std::vector<int> *v = selectFirst ? &v1 : &v2;
v->push_back(0);
```

But how to insert or erase values from v ???

Thank you

Comment: Do "v->insert()" and "v->erase()" not work for some reason?

Comment: Why don't you use a reference instead of a pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the same way you used `push_back`, you can use `erase`... Look at the documentation for those operations in the STL. For example, deleting the first element:

```
v->erase( v->begin() );
```